# Equivalent of Joe in spanish?

Tags: nombres-propios

I want to remember what a friend's name was I just met. It's on the tip of my tongue, and I keep wanting to say Yohio or Yojo. It was not Jose. I don't remember. He went by Joe as well. I remember it being a pretty cool name, and I want to remember how to say it.

Comment: Very interesting question. Definitely Joe is short of Joseph which in Spanish is José. Could it be he just went by Joe because people just could not pronounce his name properly and it sounds more or less similar? Do you know where is your friend from?

Comment: Jorge, Joel, Jonas Jordi... ? It may help to know the country and region of your friend.

Comment: I'm really not at all sure this question is on topic... it's about remembering someone's name, and really seems to have nothing to do with the Spanish language.

Comment: Look for it http://www.sitiosargentina.com.ar/Nombres/masculinos/J.htm

Comment: Agree with @SergioRomero so Jose

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Jordi? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordi

Comment: Jordi is a catalan name, not spanish.

Answer (score 0):

The name you are trying to remember is [José](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9).